# Doubt regarding Compactness argument used in Proof

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

In that Book I come across following theorem.[image]

Notation [image]

Author mentioned that by standard argument of compact we can extract sequnce such that $A_{t_{k-1}^{-1}A_{t_k}}\in V$.

I do not understand this standard argument .

I would be really thankful If someone help me out

Any Help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** The operation $\varphi:G\times G\to G,\ (A,B)\mapsto A^{-1}B$ is continuous, hence so is $[0,1]\times[0,1]\to G,\ (t, s) \mapsto A(t)^{-1}A(s)$. 
Then the preimage of $V$ is open. 
(You can also rely on a metric, if you wish, given by matrix norm.)

Comment: Sir V is already given to be an open neighbourhood of I in G. I still do not understand. Can you please elaborate? Thanks a lot

Comment: As an open set, $\varphi^{-1}(V)$ is a union of open balls, hence the diagonal $\{(t,t):t\in[0,1]\}$ can be covered by *finitely many* of them. Let $\varepsilon$ be the radius of the smallest ball among these, then $A(t)^{-1}A(s)\in V$ whenever $|s-t|<\varepsilon$.

Comment: Thanks a lot... I required some time to digest argument. But Once I understand ... I became too happy AS it uses very basic idea and bypasses very High End tools....Once again thanks....